# Why i can't configure my mobile app service in azure portal for xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services, azureportal

I'm developing a mobile app for `iOS` and `Android` with `Xamarin`.Forms through `Visual Studio IDE`. In order to connect my application with my Azure `SQL database`, I wanted to configure in the quickstart screen my mobile service for `Xamarin`.Forms. Unfortunately, the quickstart screen suddenly changed and I can't anymore configure the service for `Xamarin`.forms. Instead, I have to face out with this screen:

[image: quickstart Azure App Service]

Can I have some assistance about it?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile apps Quickstart experience from Azure portal is changed and we are making changes to the documentation to reflect the new instructions. The updated docs will be live in a few days. Sorry for the inconvenience that it might have caused.

Comment: Update: 
We’ve made the documentation changes and its live now. Could you please refer the steps outlined in the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started and share any feedback you may have within the doc feedback option.